# Making Firebase Database ultra secure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cryptography, firebase-security

I am trying to write perfect database rules for Firebase to block people from seeing each other's data. Every user has a API key saved on the database like this:

```
-users:
    -user1:
       -APIKEY: "123asdasasd"
```

I am allowing the users to only set their API keys but they are not even able to see their saved API keys themselves. This is my security rule for that:

```
"users": {
        "$userID": {
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $userID",
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.admin === true " 
        }
    },
```

So even if someone impersonates some other user, they cannot access their data, only they can change it, and that is not a security problem for my app.

Because my app needs to be ultra secure, **I also want to add cryptography to the database**. I want the client to encrypt the API keys before saving on the database, and only my server will know the key to decrypt those API keys. So the keys stored on the database will be encrypted.

Is there any way a hacker who has access to my whole database be able to decrypt people's API keys without knowing the decryption key?

What are some good methods for cryptography in node.js? If the server knows a private key and no-one else knows that private key, is it simply secure?

Comment: Please explain what it means for a hacker to have "hacked my whole database".

Comment: @DougStevenson seeing whatever there is in my database

Comment: The only way that could happen is if someone had your Google account password.  At that point, your project could be in seriously bad shape, and I'm not sure what you could really do to stop them.

Comment: Are you stating that *even if someone impersonates some other user, they cannot access their data, only they can change it,*. So if I impersonate you, and change your key to something I know then I would know your key, right? That doesn't sound very secure - maybe I misunderstand? Also, storing an API key on the client in the clear can be a security problem as well. I would suggest not leaning to hard on 'API keys' and leverage user accounts with authentication for security - Firebase authentication works well for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the term "keys" for a few different things, which unfortunately makes it hard to answer. I'll give it a try though, since the main thing to consider is where you store the keys used for encrypting/decrypting the data.

1. If you store the encryption/decryption keys in the same database as the values that you encrypt with them, then anyone with access to that database can decrypt the data.
2. If you store the encryption/decryption keys in another database than where you store the encrypted values, then a malicious will need access to both databases to be able to decrypt the values with the key.

Of course both approaches are susceptible to brute force attacks. So if your encryption is not sufficiently strong, the whole point of encrypting the data is moot.

Recommending specific libraries for encryption is off-topic on Stack Overflow btw, but a few well targeted Google searches should give you plenty of good candidates.